# Remove \n from text in a JSON field

Tags: python, dataframe

I save a JSON response saved down in a txt file from JIRA.

I'm then successfully reading the txt file in and converting to a dataframe and normalising the fields.  However some of the fields in JIRA have "\n" in them, so when it converts to a dataframe I'm getting extra rows and it's not quite parsing it properly.

How can I remove these \n from the values?

I've tried using strip but get an error.  My code is:

```
with open(fInput, encoding='ute-16') as inputfile:
inputfile = inputfile.strip()
```

The error I get is: io.TextIOWrapper object has no attribute 'strip'

Example json from JIRA (summary object under the fields object under the issues object)

```
{
"expand": "schema,names",
"startAt": 0,
"maxResults": 50,
"total": 6,
"issues": [
    {
        "expand": "html",
        "id": "10230",
        "self": "http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/BULK-62",
        "key": "BULK-62",
        "fields": {
            "summary": "testing\n\n",
            "timetracking": null,
            "issuetype": {
                "self": "http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issuetype/5",
                "id": "5",
                "description": "The sub-task of the issue",
                "iconUrl": "http://localhost:8080/images/icons/issue_subtask.gif",
                "name": "Sub-task",
                "subtask": true
            }
    }
]
```

}

Comment: `strip()`, if you use it correctly, is a string method that removes whitespace (including newlines) from the beginning and the end of strings. I doubt this is what you need here. IIUC, you may have newlines in the middle of strings too. Right?

Comment: yes, there is \n mid string too on some fields

Comment: The `.strip()` function is used for strings, your `inputfile` is not a string, but a `TextIOWrapper` file object like the error mentions, so you can't use the function as it is currently. You would need to read the file and then replace all the `\n`.

Comment: There should not be `\n` in JSON strings, it should be escaped as `\\n`.

Comment: The text in the field returned is as per the example "some text \n\n"

Answer (score 0):

If you actually get JSON (i.e. with escaped `\n`), then there is no problen loading it as one row.

```py
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_json(StringIO("""\
{
    "expand": "schema,names",
    "startAt": 0,
    "maxResults": 50,
    "total": 6,
    "issues": [
        {
            "expand": "html",
            "id": "10230",
            "self": "http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/BULK-62",
            "key": "BULK-62",
            "fields": {
                "summary": "testing\\n\\n",
                "timetracking": null,
                "issuetype": {
                    "self": "http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issuetype/5",
                    "id": "5",
                    "description": "The sub-task of the issue",
                    "iconUrl": "http://localhost:8080/images/icons/issue_subtask.gif",
                    "name": "Sub-task",
                    "subtask": true
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}"""))

pd.json_normalize(df["issues"])
#   expand     id                                            self  ...                           fields.issuetype.iconUrl fields.issuetype.name fields.issuetype.subtask
# 0   html  10230  http://localhost:8080/rest/api/2/issue/BULK-62  ...  http://localhost:8080/images/icons/issue_subta...              Sub-task                     True

# [1 rows x 12 columns]
```

Comment: how do I use stringIO when opening the file using:

with open(fInput, encoding='ute-16') as inputfile:

as I get another error that isn't expecting an IOWrapper

Comment: StringIO is used to avoid creating and reading from a file to make the answer self contained. Keep on using `pd.read_json(file_name)` or `pd.read_json(file_handle)`.